# React: How to get Parent component's width from Child component with hooks?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-hooks

Say I have 2 components, `Parent` and `Child`. I need a way to access `Parents`'s width in `Child`, and also need `useEffect` to fire off some code whenever this width changes.

Attempting with `useRef` gives me an error along the lines of `Cannot access clientWidth property of undefined` when I use a reference on the `parent`, and pass it as a prop to `child`, and try to access it through `parentRef.current.clientWidth`.

**Snippet**

```js
const parentRef = useRef();

return(
  <Parent ref={parentRef}>
    <Child parentRef={parentRef}/>
  </Parent>
)
```

What do I do?

Comment: how do you pass the ref?

Comment: @e.a. Added in the original answer.

Comment: sorry. I meant how are you using it in the child component. are you using forwardRef? because you can't consume it like a normal prop

Comment: @e.a. I am using it as a normal prop. What's a `forwardedRef`? Can you show me an example?

Comment: I posted in the answers to show you the code. It would solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to access ref in your child component, you need to wrap you component in a React.forwardRef function & use the ref as the second argument & not inside the props object so:

```
const Child = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {})
```

& in your parent you would have:

```
<Child ref={parentRef}/>
```

you can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactforwardref)

Comment: So, if I understand it correctly, I create a parent container with, say `<div ref={parentRef}>`, where `parentRef` is created with `const parentRef = useRef()`, and then export child component like `export default forwardRef((props, ref) => {})`, and get a handle to parent by `ref.current`, right?

Comment: yes. other than the export part. where's the name of the component? :)  you can either use a named function & say `export default forwardRef(function Child (props, ref) {})` or as most people are used to, define a variable for an anonymous function like ` const Child = forwardRef((props, ref) => {})` and then `export default Child` at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Make state in parent
Make function takes value and change the state
Pass function from parent to child in props
Execute the function in child with width value

Comment: Could you please clarify what you said?

Comment: Okay I get you now!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `ResizeObserver` api to listen for the resize event attached on your `Parent`

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

const Child = ({ width = 0 }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    // listen for the change in width
    // do something here when the width changes
  }, [width]);

  return <p> Parent Div Size: {width} </p>;
};

const Parent = () => {
  const divRef = useRef(null);
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
      // this callback gets executed whenever the size changes
      // when size changes get the width and update the state
      // so that the Child component can access the updated width
      for (let entry of entries) {
        if (entry.contentRect) {
          setWidth(entry.contentRect.width);
        }
      }
    });

    // register the observer for the div
    resizeObserver.observe(divRef.current);

    // unregister the observer
    return () => resizeObserver.unobserve(divRef.current);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      ref={divRef}
      style={{
        textAlign: "center",
        height: "100px",
        border: "solid 1px"
      }}
    >
      <Child width={width} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Parent;
```

[Working Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-lake-zbu8d?file=/src/App.js:0-793)

**Reference**

[Resize Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver)